# Hide divs that are not shown on page using Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to hide divs that are not shown on my page. I'm using infinite scroll and can't find a way to select what it is not shown on page.
E.x. Let's say that 8 card views are full shown in a loaded page, when infinite scroll loads 8 more and scroll down to first two you can see 8 in total. (6 from the first 8 group and 2 from the second 8 group. The first two card views should be hidden and the 4 last card views should also be hidden).

I tried using a library called virtual-scroller and didn't work. I then tried something with the scroll location but can't find to understand it.

Comment: Hey, check out [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and i'll come back and see how I can help you once you've updated your question, pictures may help but copy any relevant code that may help us help you directly into your question as well, talk soon!

Comment: Are you trying to achieve virtual scrolling? If you are, the best library to use is Angular Material's SDK, here: https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview
It automatically removes the DOM nodes that are no longer in view.